# Notation::gshadw warning when using Symbolize inside If

Tags: contexts, initialization, custom-notation

Somewhere in my `init.m` file I have the following code:

```
If[$FrontEnd =!= Null,
    Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;
    Needs["Notation`"];
    Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
    Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox["_","_"]]];
];
```

This causes Mathematica to print the following warning when starting up:

```
Notation::gshadw: 
    The symbol 'Symbolize' has been used in the global context. The Notation
 package needs the full use of the symbol 'Symbolize
' and has therefore removed this symbol from the global context.
```

If I remove the `If` it works without Mathematica printing the warning, but then I will get an error when running Mathematica from the command line.

Why is this happening? Is the context somehow different inside the `If`?

Is there a way to keep this code without producing the error (without using `Off`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the expression is being read in and parsed **before** being evaluated, which means that the symbols `Symbolize` and `ParsedBoxWrapper` are created before the `` "Notation`" `` context is placed on the `$ContextPath` by `Needs`. Without seeing the symbols in `` "Notation`" ``, Mathematica creates them in the `` "Global`" `` context, leading to the shadowing.

You can avoid this by loading the package in a separate expression from the `Symbolize`s, like so:

```
If[$FrontEnd =!= Null,
  Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;
  Needs["Notation`"]];

If[$FrontEnd =!= Null,
  Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
  Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox["_", "_"]]]];
```